# Lookup function not working in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets where the first dataset has following output:

```
Id Name

2  John
2  John
3   MCK
```

The second dataset has following output:

```
Id Role

2  Student
3  Master
```

I have mapped first dataset to my table. Now I need to show the name from first dataset and role from second dataset where role is Student only. I tried using below lookup expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Role.Value, "DataSet2")
```

but it is not returning any data.

Kindly help

Comment: You sure there are matching data for the both datasets ? And also check for the datatypes of both the `Id` columns in both tables if they are same.

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup function cannot be used to apply filters - see restrictions according to the MSDN documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531(v=sql.105).aspx

If you combine the two datasets (i.e. if these are sql, by joining them), you can then filter on this combined dataset.

Comment: You can't use a Lookup as a filter, but you can return a result that can be used to set the visibility of a row - i.e. set the Hidden property of the row such that rows where the Lookup does not return "Student" are hidden. Or you can join the data in the source query as suggested (this is the best option if it's possible).